# Deployments not visible in Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I've created a deployment like this:

```
kubectl run my-app --image=ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-app:v1 -l name=my-app --replicas=1
```

Now I goto the Kubernetes Dashboard:

```
https://172.0.0.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
```

But I dont see `my-app` listed here.

Is it possible to use the Kubernetes Dashboard to view deployments? I'd like to use the dashboard to do things like view the deployments mem/cpu usage, check logs, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kubernetes Dashboard is pretty limited at the moment, and only supports ReplicationControllers. If you create a ReplicationController then you will be able to see the Pods connected to it, check their memory and CPU usage, and view their logs.

Work is being done to improve Dashboard and in the future it should support other Kubernetes resources besides ReplicationControllers. You can see some mockups in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/design/navigation-and-scale.md).

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the Dashboard UI maintainers.

Deployments will be shown in the UI in next release (a few weeks from now). I'm sorry this wasn't done before, but we had tight schedule. If you want to test the features sooner, use v1.1.0-beta2 version of the UI which will be released next week.

Comment: Update: FYI, deployments are now fully supported in the UI