# Replication Controller VS Deployment in Kubernetes

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I wanted to know what is the difference between a Replication Controller and a Deployment within Kubernetes (1.2). Going through the getting started document (http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/) I have created a deployment - but it doesn't show up on the web UI.

When I create apps from the web UI - they are created as replication controllers. Functionally though, they seem very similar (they both manage pods and have services).

So - what is the difference and when should I use each?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Deployments are a newer and higher level concept than Replication Controllers. They manage the deployment of Replica Sets (also a newer concept, but pretty much equivalent to Replication Controllers), and allow for easy updating of a Replica Set as well as the ability to roll back to a previous deployment.

Previously this would have to be done with `kubectl rolling-update` which was not declarative and did not provide the rollback features.

<strike>Kubernetes Dashboard has not yet been updated to support Deployments, and currently only supports Replication Controllers (see [Deployments not visible in Kubernetes Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305133/deployments-not-visible-in-kubernetes-dashboard/37305814#37305814)).</strike>

EDIT: The dashboard now supports Deployments.

Comment: So should Deployments be used for newer applications? Also - is there any ways to get the stats on deployments / their pods (CPU, mem usage) using the kubectl cli?

Comment: Personally I have held off using Deployments so far due to the lack of Dashboard support. I don't know that any such commands exist - I think you would have to somehow query [Heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) directly.

Comment: You can get the stats on deployments using `kubectl get deployments`, `kubectl describe deployments`, and `kubectl get pods -l <the label you put in deployment pod spec, e.g. foo=bar>`

Comment: @janetkuo AFAIK none of those commands will actually show you CPU or memory usage, but let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @PixelElephant I missed the fact that you're looking for CPU/memory usage. We don't have that kind of commands now, but we're planning to add `kubectl top` command which will support this. Please feel free to comment on the [related issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11382).

Answer (score 18):

Here is the latest *2020 answer* to the question started in 2016, 4 years ago

A good answer is given in 2017
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/kubernetes-replication-controller-replica-set-and-deployments-understanding-replication-options/

Now we are in **Kubernetes version - 1.17**, we got 3 types

**Deployment (Recommended)**

Deployment is a higher-level API object that updates its underlying Replica Sets and their Pods in a similar fashion as kubectl rolling-update. Deployments are recommended if you want this rolling update functionality, because unlike kubectl rolling-update, they are declarative, server-side, and have additional features.

**ReplicaSet**

ReplicaSet is the next-generation ReplicationController that supports the new set-based label selector. It’s mainly used by Deployment as a mechanism to orchestrate pod creation, deletion and updates. Note that we recommend using Deployments instead of directly using Replica Sets, unless you require custom update orchestration or don’t require updates at all.

**ReplicationController (Not Recommended)**

Ensures that a specified number of pod replicas are running at any one time. In other words, a ReplicationController makes sure that a pod or a homogeneous set of pods is always up and available.

Answer (score 8):

[Deployments](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) are still in beta (their API is under `extensions/v1beta1`), which is probably why they don't show up in the UI. They automate state transitions on top of just keeping pods alive. From the linked page:

> A Deployment provides declarative updates for Pods and Replica Sets
>   (the next-generation Replication Controller). You only need to
>   describe the desired state in a Deployment object, and the Deployment
>   controller will change the actual state to the desired state at a
>   controlled rate for you. You can define Deployments to create new
>   resources, or replace existing ones by new ones.

They also provide rollout history and other useful features.

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment/nginx-deployment
deployments "nginx-deployment":
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
1           kubectl create -f docs/user-guide/nginx-deployment.yaml --record
2           kubectl apply -f docs/user-guide/new-nginx-deployment.yaml
3           kubectl apply -f docs/user-guide/bad-nginx-deployment.yaml
```

It keeps track of the changes too.

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment/nginx-deployment --revision=2
deployments "nginx-deployment" revision 2
Labels:     app=nginx,pod-template-hash=1564180365
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/change-cause=kubectl apply -f docs/user-guide/new-nginx-deployment.yaml
Image(s):   nginx:1.9.1
No volumes.
```

Answer (score 7):

Now with [release 1.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases/tag/v1.1.0) Dashboard does support Deployments. You can deploy or update your dashboard without having to wait for the 1.3 release of k8s. You can for example use the [official YAML](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml), which we just changed to use Deployments today.

Generally, I'd recommend (and folks from Google and Kubernetes contributors also do) using Deployments over RCs as they are a much more powerful primitive (include rolling updates, versioning/auditing, canaray/green-blue deployments, rollbacks, etc.).

Comment: btw, I recently wrote a blog post about Deployments and why to use them: https://blog.giantswarm.io/understanding-basic-kubernetes-concepts-using-deployments-manage-services-declaratively/

Answer (score 2):

The dashboard (web UI) has been hugely redesigned to support managing more resources (like `Deployments` and `DaemonSets`, etc.) and the current dashboard doesn't allow much regarding `Deployments`.

Managing Deployments in dashboard will be supported soon in kubernetes 1.3 (refer to issue [Feature request: handle Deployments](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/595)).

Answer (score 2):

From my experience deployments provide not all the functionality I need. Or, maybe, I am using them in a wrong fashion.

When there is a need to restart node server - all pods running on that server started by deployment - do fail. And I can not find a way to avoid this.

But,

Think solution is a replication controller. At least in description it is written that it handles such cases.

Main deployment advantage, as I see it, is when you need to change version of your app constantly.

So both ways are good but for different reasons.

Comment: There is no difference between Replication Controller and Deployment for this case (after all a Deployment is just a wrapper around a Replica Set). What you want to do is [drain](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_drain/) the node before restarting it. Once it is back in action you can [uncordon](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_uncordon/) it to let it start accepting pods again.

Comment: and how to deal with it if node fails unexpectedly? I mean - If i have no chance to drain it?

Comment: maybe a bit late to the party, but i would think that running a daemonset is supposed to solve this @TomasŠatas

Answer (score 0):

2023:

Replication Controller VS Deployment in Kubernetes

replication controller is the old version of replica set.

so replication controller(rc) vs replica set(rs) vs deployment(deploy).

rs can work with set-based selectors. rc can not.

some time before we could automatically update pods of rc via

kubectl rolling-update old_rc_manifest   -f  new_rc_manifest

now this feature is removed from kubectl.

if we create rs manually we can not automatically update its pods - that is there is no any command that delete old pods one by one and create new pods one by one. we should do it manually. However if we create rs via deployment then we can update pods automatically using deploy features.

so rc is the old stuff with no pros. instead use rs.
if we want to update pods of rs in a usefull manner do not create rs manually , instead use deploy. deploy automatically create rs, rs create pods.