# Is it safe to replace ReplicationController with Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, katacoda

I am practicing [katacoda k8s lesson](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/guestbook) with the knowledge from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423117/replication-controller-vs-deployment-in-kubernetes). I had tried kill the pods by command line and the result of them are exactly the same with simple example. The pod will get recreated in several moment later after dead.

**Question:**
Can I just simply replace the `ReplicationController` with `Deployment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use replication controller. Those are replaced with ReplicaSet.

In your case, use deployment object to manage the application life cycle. With deployment you would be able to control rolling upgrade and, rollbabk features of kubernetes

Deployment object works one layer above ReplicaSet and allows you to upgrade the app to new version with zero downtime