# Is replicaset a control plane layer responsibility?

Tags: kubernetes

Namespace isolated containers(Pod) & Nodes hosting the Pods are part of data plane

`kubectl describe pod [pod-name]` command talks to API server and provide information like node details, date started, and the troubleshooting events etc...stored in `etcd`

`kubelet`'s probe from dataplane(on every node)  takes care of healthcheck of all containers within pod.

---

Is replicaset functionality part of control plane?

To ensure the DESIRED state of replica set, which component in *control plane* probes data plane ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `kube-controller-manager` under which kubernetes is running several type of controllers.

> The Kubernetes controller manager is a daemon that embeds the core
> control loops shipped with Kubernetes. In applications of robotics and
> automation, a control loop is a non-terminating loop that regulates
> the state of the system. **In Kubernetes, a controller is a control loop
> that watches the shared state of the cluster through the apiserver and
> makes changes attempting to move the current state towards the desired
> state.** Examples of controllers that ship with Kubernetes today are the
> replication controller, endpoints controller, namespace controller,
> and serviceaccounts controller.
>
> kube-controller-manager [flags]

Here is the example `--controllers` flag showing what all controllers can be controlled by `kube-controller-manager` , by changing this flag, you may exclude some of the controllers.

```
kubectl get pod -n kube-system kube-controller-manager-controlplane -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].command}'
["kube-controller-manager","--allocate-node-cidrs=true","--authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf","--authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf","--bind-address=127.0.0.1","--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt","--cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16","--cluster-name=kubernetes","--cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt","--cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key","--controllers=*,bootstrapsigner,tokencleaner","--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf","--leader-elect=true","--port=0","--requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt","--root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt","--service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key","--service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12","--use-service-account-credentials=true"]
```

In the above output you can see that all(`*`) controllers are selected by default:

```
--controllers=*
```

As per documentation, following is the complete list of the controllers working under `kube-controller-manager`.

> --controllers strings     Default: "*"

A list of controllers to enable. '*' enables all on-by-default controllers,

> 'foo' enables the
> controller named 'foo', '-foo' disables the controller named 'foo'.
> All controllers: attachdetach, bootstrapsigner, cloud-node-lifecycle,
> clusterrole-aggregation, cronjob, csrapproving, csrcleaner,
> csrsigning, daemonset, deployment, disruption, endpoint,
> endpointslice, endpointslicemirroring, ephemeral-volume,
> garbagecollector, horizontalpodautoscaling, job, namespace, nodeipam,
> nodelifecycle, persistentvolume-binder, persistentvolume-expander,
> podgc, pv-protection, pvc-protection, **replicaset**,
> **replicationcontroller**, resourcequota, root-ca-cert-publisher, route,
> service, serviceaccount, serviceaccount-token, statefulset,
> tokencleaner, ttl, ttl-after-finished Disabled-by-default controllers:
> bootstrapsigner, tokencleaner

Comment: For Pod lifecycle, do we have any controller dedicated in control plane? or does kubelet from data plane would suffice to take care of Pod lifecycle?

Comment: pods are managed by kubelet, check out interesting read here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states

Comment: How is the term deployment(`kind: Deployment`) different from replicaset?

Comment: deployment is having some additions features over replicaset, one of them is upgrade strategies in deployment. you can have the pods under deployment upgraded using rolling or recreate. This is not present in replicaset by itself. Also, when a deployment is created, it automatically create a replicaset. there are more, but this is the high level gist. TLDR, typically replica-set is created by deployments and replicasets are not created standalone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423117/replication-controller-vs-deployment-in-kubernetes