# Kubernetes - when to use HorizontalPodAutoscaler resource type?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, replicaset

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423281/3317808): allow for easy updating of a Replica Set as well as the ability to roll back to a previous deployment.

So, `kind: Deployment` scales replicasets, which scales Pods, supports zero-downtime updates by creating and destroying replicasets

---

What is the purpose of `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` resource type?

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: xyz
spec:
  maxReplicas: 4
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: xyz
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write, with a `Deployment` it is easy to *manually* scale an app horizontally, by changing the numer of replicas.

By using a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler`, you can *automate* the horizontal scaling by e.g. configuring some metric thresholds, therefore the name **autoscaler**.

Comment: So, where has the automation happened for scaling? in the given template

Comment: the HPA will update the replicas in your Deployment

Comment: ok, so without changing the existing deployment, HPA change the replicaset property of running deployment.

Comment: It changes the `replicas:` field in the Deployment object.